# socket.io - Client-Side Security

Tags: node.js, express, websocket, socket.io, passport.js

I have a question about websocket security. For example, take a chat feature using socket.io/express/passport for authentication. Like this:

```
socket.emit('chatMessage', {
    msg: $('#m').val(),
    userid: '{{user.id}}'
});
```

Is this secure? Could someone fake their identity when sending messages? If so, what would be a better way to approach this. Thanks!

Comment: You cannot trust anything from the client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That way isn't secure, unless he's sending a token provided by you.

The best way is to authenticate the user once, when he connects to the server, instead of sending credentials on every `.emit`

```
io.use(async(socket, next) => {

    try {
        // Use cookies, or query with a token provided 
        // by oAUTH or any kind of authentication method, or whatever method you whish
        await authenticate(socket); 

        return next();

    } catch(err) {

        return next(new Error('Authentication error'));
    }

});

io.on('connection', socket => /* ... */);
```

If auhtentication is valid, every `emit` will be from an authenticated socket.

Answer (score 0):

You using nodejs socket.io, you can install cors in nodejs, after then import cors
var cors = require('cors');

you see:https://hoanguyenit.com/huong-dan-ket-hop-nodejs-vuejs.html
https://hoanguyenit.com/chat-nodejs-vuejs.html

Comment: Welcome on Stack Overflow! Would be great if you could replace your links by English references because this portal is using English for all users. Thanks!